# Stable Baselines3 Parameter Logits has invalid values

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I am trying to run stable baselines on sports games but keep getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/Desktop/Projects/AI/NBA2/stable_baselines_run.py", line 35, in <module>
    model.learn(total_timesteps=10000)
  File "/home/dev/anaconda3/envs/sb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/a2c/a2c.py", line 189, in learn
    return super(A2C, self).learn(
  File "/home/dev/anaconda3/envs/sb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/on_policy_algorithm.py", line 234, in learn
    continue_training = self.collect_rollouts(self.env, callback, self.rollout_buffer, n_rollout_steps=self.n_steps)
  File "/home/dev/anaconda3/envs/sb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/on_policy_algorithm.py", line 166, in collect_rollouts
    actions, values, log_probs = self.policy.forward(obs_tensor)
  File "/home/dev/anaconda3/envs/sb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/policies.py", line 566, in forward
    distribution = self._get_action_dist_from_latent(latent_pi, latent_sde=latent_sde)
  File "/home/dev/anaconda3/envs/sb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/policies.py", line 607, in _get_action_dist_from_latent
    return self.action_dist.proba_distribution(action_logits=mean_actions)
  File "/home/dev/anaconda3/envs/sb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/distributions.py", line 326, in proba_distribution
    self.distribution = [Categorical(logits=split) for split in th.split(action_logits, tuple(self.action_dims), dim=1)]
  File "/home/dev/anaconda3/envs/sb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/distributions.py", line 326, in <listcomp>
    self.distribution = [Categorical(logits=split) for split in th.split(action_logits, tuple(self.action_dims), dim=1)]
  File "/home/dev/anaconda3/envs/sb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributions/categorical.py", line 64, in __init__
    super(Categorical, self).__init__(batch_shape, validate_args=validate_args)
  File "/home/dev/anaconda3/envs/sb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributions/distribution.py", line 53, in __init__
    raise ValueError("The parameter {} has invalid values".format(param))
ValueError: The parameter logits has invalid values
```

I have removed all NaN's (replaced with 0) and normalised the data so that all data is between 0 and 1 but still cannot find the invalid value.

Here is my custom environment:

```
import gym
from gym import spaces
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

INITIAL_BALANCE = 100

class BettingEnv(gym.Env):

# metadata = {'render.modes': ['human']}

def __init__(self, df, results, INITIAL_BALANCE=100):
    self.df = df
    self.results = results
    self.initial_balance = INITIAL_BALANCE
    self.balance = INITIAL_BALANCE
    self.profit = 0
    
    self.starting_point = np.random.randint(len(self.df) - len(self.df) * 0.1) # Start anywhere but in the end 10%
    self.timestep = 0
    self.games_won = 0
    self.game_bets = []
    self.game_number = self.starting_point + self.timestep

    self.action_space = spaces.MultiDiscrete([3,10])
    
    self.observation_space = spaces.Box(
        low = self.df.min().min(), # Lowest value found in df
        high = self.df.max().max(), # Search the df for the max value (this may change with different data)
        shape = (df.shape[1],), # shape of one row of the df
        # dtype = np.float16
    )
    print('First ob: ',self.df.loc[self.game_number])
    
def _next_obs(self):
    
    print('Get next obs')
    # Get next game row
    obs = self.df.loc[self.timestep]
    print('next obs success')
    return obs

def _print_bet_csv(self):
    
    # Create bet_info_df
    bet_info_df = pd.DataFrame(self.game_bets)
    results_df = self.results.reset_index()

    
    # #Merge dfs
    self.merged_df = pd.merge(bet_info_df, results_df, on=['index', 'Home Odds', 'Vis Odds', 'Home Win'])
    self.merged_df.set_index('index', inplace=True)
    
    # #Print df
    self.merged_df.to_csv('./temp/MLB Bot Betting DF.csv', index=True)


def _print_bet_chart(self):
    
    x_axis = [i for i in range(self.timestep)]
    plt.plot(x_axis, self.merged_df['Bankroll'])
    plt.title('Bankroll')
    plt.ylabel('Dollars')
    plt.xlabel('Games')
    plt.savefig('./temp/NBA_Bot_Betting.png')


def _take_action(self, action):
    
    print('Start action')
    # Init
    action_type = action[0]
    amount = action[1] + 1
    
    self.game_number = self.starting_point + self.timestep
    
    game_result = self.results['Home Win'][self.game_number]
    odds = 0
    bet_on = 'NA'
    
    # VISITOR BET
    if action_type == 0:
        bet_on = 'False'
        
        # Find vis odds
        odds = self.results['Vis Odds'][self.game_number]
        if odds == 0:
            amount = 0
        
        # Place bet
        self.balance -= amount
        
        # Check if win
        if game_result == False:
            self.balance += round(amount * odds, 2)
            self.games_won += 1
    
    # NO BET
    if action_type == 1: 
        bet_on = 'No bet'

    
    # HOME BET
    if action_type == 2:
        bet_on = 'True'
        
        # Find home odds
        odds = self.results['Home Odds'][self.game_number]
        if odds == 0:
            amount = 0
        
        # Place bet
        self.balance -= amount
        
        # Check win
        if game_result == True:
            self.balance += round(amount * odds, 2)
            self.games_won += 1
    
    self.balance = round(self.balance, 2)
    
    bet_info = {
        'index': self.game_number,
        'Home Odds': self.results['Home Odds'][self.game_number],
        'Vis Odds': self.results['Vis Odds'][self.game_number],
        'Bet on': bet_on,
        'Home Win': game_result,
        'Amount': amount,
        'Odds': odds,
        'Bankroll': self.balance
    }
    
    self.game_bets.append(bet_info)
    print('Finish action')
    return bet_info

def step(self, action):
    
    print('Start step')
    info = self._take_action(action)
    self.timestep += 1
    
    # Reward
    gamma = (self.timestep / len(self.df)) # time discount
    self.profit = self.balance - self.initial_balance
    reward = self.profit * gamma
    
    # Done
    done = self.balance <= 0
    
    # Obs
    obs = self._next_obs()
    
    # If last game, print results and start from beginning
    #test the printing of csv
    if self.timestep == 2500:
        self._print_bet_csv()
        self._print_bet_chart()
        self.game_bets = []
        print('Starting point: ',self.starting_point)
        print('Chart printed')
        
    print('Finished Step')
    return obs, reward, done, info

def reset(self):
    
    self.initial_balance = INITIAL_BALANCE
    self.balance = INITIAL_BALANCE
    self.profit = 0
    
    self.starting_point = np.random.randint(len(self.df) - len(self.df) * 0.1) # Start anywhere but in the end 10%
    self.timestep = 0
    self.games_won = 0
    self.game_bets = []
    

def render(self, mode='human', close=False):
    
    print('Timestep: ', self.timestep)
    print('Profit: ', self.profit)
    print('Games Won: ', self.games_won)
    print('Balance: ', self.balance)
```

Here is the file I run the environment from:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

import os
import random
import json
import gym
from gym import spaces
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines3 import PPO, A2C

from Betting_env import BettingEnv


data = pd.read_csv('Scraping/Games and Stats.csv')
df = data.drop(['Date', 'Home', 'Visitor', 'Home PTS', 'Vis PTS', 'Home Points Dif', 'Home Win'], axis=1)
df = df.astype(float)
normed = (df-df.min())/(df.max()-df.min())
normed = normed.round(10)

env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: BettingEnv(normed, data, INITIAL_BALANCE=100)])

model = A2C('MlpPolicy', env, verbose=0)

model.learn(total_timesteps=10000)

save_path = os.path.join('Training', 'Saved Models', 'Betting_Model_A2C')
model.save(save_path)

end_time = time.time()
total_time = end_time - start_time

print(round(total_time / 60 / 60), ' Hours ', round(total_time / 60), ' Minutes')
```

UPDATE:
After using the VecCheckNan() and check_env() functions by stable_baselines3 I get the following error messages.
VecCheckNan() gives:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/Desktop/Projects/AI/NBA2/stable_baselines_run.py", line 51, in <module>
    model.learn(total_timesteps=10000)
  File "/home/dev/anaconda3/envs/sb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/ppo/ppo.py", line 299, in learn
    return super(PPO, self).learn(
  File "/home/dev/anaconda3/envs/sb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/on_policy_algorithm.py", line 226, in learn
    total_timesteps, callback = self._setup_learn(
  File "/home/dev/anaconda3/envs/sb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/base_class.py", line 420, in _setup_learn
    self._last_obs = self.env.reset()  # pytype: disable=annotation-type-mismatch
  File "/home/dev/anaconda3/envs/sb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/vec_env/vec_check_nan.py", line 46, in reset
    self._check_val(async_step=False, observations=observations)
  File "/home/dev/anaconda3/envs/sb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/vec_env/vec_check_nan.py", line 84, in _check_val
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: found nan in observations.
Originated from the environment observation (at reset)
```

I have printed out the first observations and there are no NaNs in there.

check_env() gives:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/Desktop/Projects/AI/NBA2/stable_baselines_run.py", line 42, in <module>
    check_env(env)
  File "/home/dev/anaconda3/envs/sb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/env_checker.py", line 245, in check_env
    assert isinstance(
AssertionError: Your environment must inherit from the gym.Env class cf https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/core.py
```

I have gym.Env in my Betting_Env class.

Comment: Does the Betting_Env class inherit from gym.Env? `I have gym.Env in my Betting_Env class.` is not 100% clear to me.

Comment: How did you resolve it?

Comment: @tnfru, yes it is.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. In my case the problem was due to the custom reset funciton of my environment. In found that in the BaseAlgorithm class in base_class.py of stablebaselines in line 429 (in my case) is this line of code

```
self._last_obs = self.env.reset()  # pytype: disable=annotation-type-mismatch
```

, where my environment should return an observation or at least `None`.
So you could try returning an observation in your reset function.

Comment: Well done! I've been stuck with this problem for hours! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although you are replacing NaNs and ensuring that there are none, the error is mostly probably due to some of the values being np.inf or -np.inf.
Try:
`df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)`.

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

You have commented this out:

```
# dtype = np.float16
```

So you may already have tried this. But it is possible your dataframe contains a float32 and your observation space is expecting the wrong dtype. Try changing to:

```
dtype = np.float32
```